# How can I prove that $x^2y^2\leq\frac{x^4+x^4+y^4+y^4}{4}$, with real $x$ and $y$?

Tags: inequality

I know that it has something to do with AM-GM. But the geometric mean is $\sqrt[4]{xxyy}$ and the arithmetic mean is $\dfrac{x+x+y+y}{4}$.

So how do we come to the wanted inequality?

EDIT: And how can it be proven that $x^3y\leq\dfrac{x^4+x^4+x^4+y^4}{4}$?

Comment: Are you sure you wrote it right? It doesn't look true... Also, are we talking about $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: You're right soory it has to be inverted

Comment: Taking $x=y$ yields $x^4$ on the left hand side and $x^2$ on the right hand side. Neither quantity is necessary larger than the other.

Comment: Sorry again... The exponants are $4$ and not $2$

Comment: Did you also get the direction wrong? The inequality is true with $\leq$ instead of $\geq$ (to show it try to expand the inequality $(x^2 - y^2)^2 \geq 0$). As written just take $x = 0$ to get $0 \geq y^4/2$ which fails for all $y\not= 0$.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right

Comment: What's the point of writing $\frac{x^4+x^4+y^4+y^4}{4}$ instead of just $\frac{x^4+y^4}{2}$? Anyway, with $a=x^2$ and $b=y^2$ the equality $ab\le (a^2+b^2)/2$ is equivalent to $0\le (a-b)^2$ foiled and rearranged, so...

Answer (score 4):

The AM-GM inequality is
$$
\sqrt{ab}\le\frac{a+b}{2}
$$
for $a,b\ge0$. What about $a=x^4$ and $b=y^4$?

Answer (score 3):

Write the inequality as 
$$
4x^{2}y^{2} \leq 2x^{4} + 2y^{4},
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
x^{2}y^{2} = \sqrt{x^{4}y^{4}} \leq \frac{x^{4}+y^{4}}{2};
$$
but this is true by the AM-GM inequality, 
so we are done.

Answer (score 1):

Divide both sides by y to the power 4. And take x/y as u.
Make the whole inequality in terms of u in r.h.s. u will get it as whole square of u squared minus 1. This is a square and always greater than zero. Zero is in l.h.s. hence proved.

This method applies almost everytime you have such inequalities.

Answer (score 1):

With the equation you have there, you can multiply by 4 and get that the inequality is true if and only if:

$$4x^2y^2 \leq x^4+x^4+ y^4+y^4$$

That is true if and only if

$$0 \leq (x^4+x^4+ y^4+y^4) - 4x^2y^2= (x^4-2x^2y^2+y^4) + (x^4-2x^2y^2+y^4)$$

And if you consider that $x^4-2x^2y^2+y^4= (x^2-y^2)^2$, then you have that the last inequality is true if and only if

$$0 \leq (x^2-y^2)^2 + (x^2-y^2)^2$$

That is always true since they're squares of real numbers.

**EDIT FOR THE SECOND PART**

You can apply the AM-GM in this way:

Consider that for any $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$, you will have that $\frac{a^4+b^4}{2}\geq \sqrt{a^4b^4}=a^2b^2$, so:

$$ \frac{x^4+x^4+x^4+y^4}{4}= \frac{x^4+x^4}{4}+\frac{x^4+y^4}{4} \geq \frac{x^2x^2}{2} +\frac{x^2y^2}{2} = \frac{x^4+ x^2y^2}{2}$$

Then you apply again considering the sign of $y$. If $y=0$, then your inequality is always true. If $y<0$, you will have the left side negative and the right side positive, so it's true. If $y>0$, then:

$$\frac{x^4+ x^2y^2}{2} \geq \sqrt{x^4(x^2y^2)}= x^3y$$

So finally you get:

$$ \frac{x^4+x^4+x^4+y^4}{4} \geq \frac{x^4+ x^2y^2}{2} \geq \sqrt{x^4(x^2y^2)}= x^3y $$